# Can't compile Erlang R14B03 when trying install RabbitMQ using Homebrew on Mac OS X

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, celery, homebrew

I am developing a django app and it will utilize the Celery notification system. To use Celery I need the install the RabbitMQ server. I am trying to install it using homebrew. So I just:

```
sudo brew install rabbitmq
```

But erlang is a prerquisit for the install. So Homebrew tries to compile erlang-otp (R14B03), but during this process it always gets stuck for hours. I even let it sit over night and nothing happend. So I aborted the compilation and did:

```
sudo brew install -v erlang
```

to see the progress of the compile. It gets stuck a the and states the following error:

```
=== Entering application hipe
(cd ../main && make hipe.hrl)
sed -e "s;%VSN%;3.8;" ../../hipe/main/hipe.hrl.src > ../../hipe/main/hipe.hrl
erlc -W  +debug_info +inline -o../ebin hipe_rtl.erl
(no error logger present) error: "Error in process <0.1.0> with exit value: {{badfun,[<<5 bytes>>,<<69 bytes>>,<<9 bytes>>,<<3 bytes>>,<<2 bytes>>,<<5 bytes>>,<<11 bytes>>,<<2 bytes>>,<<8 bytes>>,<<8 bytes>>,<<5 bytes>>,<<7 bytes>>,<<5 bytes>>,<<11 bytes>>,<<2 bytes>>,<<11 bytes>>,<<15 bytes>>,<<4 bytes>>,<<72 bytes>>,<<5 bytes>>,<<1 byte>>,<<7 bytes>>,<<10 bytes>>,<<7 bytes>>,<<6 bytes>>,<<7 bytes>>,<<7 bytes>>,<<6 bytes>>,<<12 bytes>>]},[{erlang,apply,2}]}\n"
```

I've tried it multiple times, but I get he same result. Could be because I have the wrong version of autoconf? Have any of you guys had a similar experience? What are some recommendations to get a successful compile?

I appreciate the help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The following site worked for me (installing from source on OS X part)
http://wiki.basho.com/Installing-Erlang.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erlang has problems building with Xcode 4's compilers.

You should be able to get it to compile if you turn off optimization with CFLAGS=-O0.

Comment: thanks for responding. can I turn off the optimization using homebrew?

Comment: Strange. I've built Erlang both using Homebrew and on my own using XCode 4 without problems. I never had to change any compiler flags for it to work...

Comment: Also, Homebrew should build **without** HiPE on OS X: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/erlang.rb

Answer (score 0):

You can get a pre-compiled package for Mac OSX from [Erlang Solutions](http://www.erlang-solutions.com/section/98/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a new Lion install with Xcode 4.1.  The following command installed erlang successfully.

```
brew install erlang --use-gcc
```